# How to add multiple field of AutoComplete with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, search, autocomplete, laravel-5

I'm new for Laravel 5.2 and I want to create user search with autocomplete to add many user to use an article or something.
Now I have found some of example for autocomplete and that's work fine.
**But I want to add another search field for add another user and choose role for each user to that article.**

Please help me to find the solution or some advice to make it possible.
Thank you.

This is my code

**index.blade.php**

`{{ Form::open(['action' => ['SearchController@autocomplete'], 'method' => 'GET']) }}
   {{ Form::text('q1', '', ['id' =>  'q1', 'class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width:250px', 'placeholder' =>  'Search users']) }}
 {{ Form::close() }}`

**JS**

```
<script>
$(function()
{
     $( "#q1" ).autocomplete({
      source: "{{ url('search/autocomplete') }}",
      minLength: 3,
      select: function(event, ui) {
//      $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
          event.preventDefault()
                $('#q1').val(ui.item.name);
      }//end select
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
                    .append("<a>" + item.name + " : " + item.email + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
        };
});
</script>
```

**SearchController**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function autocomplete(){
    $term = Input::get('term');

    $results = array();

    $queries = DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
        ->take(10)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id, 'name' => $query->name, 'email' => $query->email ];
    }
    return Response::json($results);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE SCHEMA**
Now it still a draft and not sure about detail fields.
but I think I have some Table like this

> **User Table** > for stored userID and username and more.
>
> **Exam Table** > for store examID and more... (This table for create an examID to add many user for test the exam and store userID , examID
>   to Coordinate Table)
>
> **Coordinate Table** (Coordinate Model) > for store an examID and all of userIDs and userRole has recieve by your code and have field like
>   below (role maybe change to textNOTE)
>   id  |  exam_id  |  user_id  |  role

Comment: Could you please elaborate what are those two search fields for ? I'm unable to get it.

Comment: @jaysingkar  That's mean I can search user with autocomplete and when I found and select that user and I must choose user role from select box then I submit to add that user and role of user to array for do it again and again to add many user and role to database.
My English is not good, Sorry about that.

Comment: which controller is going to handle your add user role request ?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works. I'm not able to provide the complete working code as I don't have any idea of your remaining code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you want to add the user and its role repeatedly without refreshing the page. Assuming this is the case you can follow following steps.

Note: below code is the minimal illustration to clarify the steps.

**Role Model** :- (Stored in App\Models directory)(assuming you have diffrent roles table)

```
<?php    
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['role'];

    public function User(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

**User Controller** :- (Stored in App\HTTP\Controllers directory)
To handle add request and inset the data in DB

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Role;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class userController extends Controller
{

    public static function addRole(Request $request)
    {
         User::where('id',$request->user_id)
               ->Role()
               ->create($request->only(['role']));        
        }
    }
```

Add a route to handle the request:-

```
Route::post('/add/user', array('uses' => 'userController@addUser'));
```

Add a form in your View which will add the user:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => ['userController@addUser'], 'method' => 'POST','id'=>'add_role_form']) }}
   {{ Form::hidden('id', '', array('id' => 'id','class' => 'form-control')) }}
   {{ Form::text('name', '', ['id' =>  'name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>  'Search users','disabled' => 'disabled']) }}
   {{ Form::select('role', array('admin' => 'Admin', 'Editor' => 'Editor'),['id' =>  'role', 'class' => 'form-control']); }}
{{Form::button('Click Me!','id' =>  'addRole', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary','obclick'=>'addRole();'])}}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

JS to add user role using ajax:

```
<script>
function addRole(){
$('#add_role_form').preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('#add_role_form').attr('action'),
            data: $('#add_role_form').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                // Do something
            },
            error: function (result) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

PS: Please add a JS script to assign user_id of selected user to hidden id filed in #add_role_form.

### UPDATE:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Form</title>

        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                console.log($('#userForm input:last'));
                var user = Array('User1','User2','User3','User4','User5','User6');<!-- User data. Not required if serviceUrl option is provided-->
                $('#user').autocomplete({
                    lookup: user, <!-- Use user variable as data source. Not required if serviceUrl option is provided for ajax request -->
                    tabDisabled:true,
                    showNoSuggestionNotice:true,
                        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    }
                });
                var role = Array('Role1','Role2','Role3','Role4','Role5','Role6');<!-- Role data. Not required if serviceUrl option is provided-->
                $('#role').autocomplete({
                    lookup: role, <!-- Use role variable as data source. Not required if serviceUrl option is provided for ajax request -->
                    tabDisabled:true,
                    showNoSuggestionNotice:true,
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    }
                });
            });
            var count = 0; <!-- Counter to keep track of elements i.e. user->role pairs -->
            function add(){<!-- Function to insert user and role pair as input to form -->
                $('#userForm input:last')
                        .before($('<label>')
                                .attr('for','data['+count+'][user]')
                                .text('User')
                        )
                        .before($('<input>')
                                .attr('type', 'text')
                                .attr('name','data['+count+'][user]')
                                .val($('#user').val())
                        )
                        .before($('<label>')
                                .attr('for','data['+count+'][role]')
                                .text('Role')
                        )
                        .before($('<input>')
                                .attr('type', 'text')
                                .attr('name','data['+count+'][role]')
                                .val($('#role').val())
                        )
                        .before($('<hr>'));
                count=count+1;
            }
        </script>

        <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

        <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">

    </head>
    <body class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Search User" /><!-- User search field -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" id="role" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Role" /><!-- Role search field. You can use Dropdown list instead of Input -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <a class="btn btn-info" onclick="add();">Add User</a> <!-- Button to add user -> role pair to form -->
        </div>
    </div>


    <form method="post" id="userForm" action="http://127.0.0.1/public/test"> <!-- user data form. This is going to be submited to server-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**ROUTE**

```
// To get Form
Route::get('test',function (){
    return View::make('test');
});

// To handle Form
Route::post('test',function (Request $request){
    var_dump($request->all());
});
```

**`var_dump`** Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'data' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'user' => string 'User1' (length=5)
          'role' => string 'Role1' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'user' => string 'User1' (length=5)
          'role' => string 'Role1' (length=5)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'user' => string 'User1' (length=5)
          'role' => string 'Role1' (length=5)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'user' => string 'User1' (length=5)
          'role' => string 'Role1' (length=5)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'user' => string 'User1' (length=5)
          'role' => string 'Role1' (length=5)
```

### Update 2:

`Coordinate` is your Model instance. And I'm considering `ID` as auto increment.

```
public function add(Request $request){
    $data = $request->data;
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value){        
        $data[$key]['exam_id'] = unique();//Inserting exam id into your received data
    }

    Coordinate::create($data);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a good answer. And I understand it But it still does not solve my problem.
because I want to find users with Auto Complete, which I can do it then. And can store searchable with JavaScript. Each time I find a user I had to choose roles to users who have been selected. 

And now I think I will keep the user and the user's role in the two-dimensional array in JavaScript. But I do not know how to send the data in an array to provide the model to be saved to a database.

Comment: Just trying to understand , you want to send the list of user and roles at once to the server and not the ajax method?

Comment: like you know the number of columns but don't know the number of rows. right ? i.e. user and role are your columns, and number of users with roles is your rows.

Comment: That's right. @jaysingkar
or you have a better way to store the data please advice me know how to do that ?
Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Thanks for the UPDATE
and Now, How to store it in database with some model (What is data format was sent to the Controller ?. If it send the array of data to a Controller for store to database. how to read the data for store each row ?)

Comment: can you post your database schema ?

Comment: Okay. Now, it still a draft and not sure about detail fields.
but I think I have some Table like this  
**User Table** > for stored userID and username and more.  
**Exam Table** > for store examID and more... (This table for create an examID to add many user for test the exam and store userID , examID to Coordinate Table)  
**Coordinate Table** (Coordinate Model) > for store an examID and all of userIDs and userRole has recieve by your code and have field like below (role maybe change to textNOTE)  
id  |  exam_id  |  user_id  |  role  
Do you understand my draft schema ?

Comment: Ohh... I have actually edited my answer with respect to first schema. Try to modify it according to your needs. Let me know if you get into any error.

Comment: Now I can do it from your guide. It's very useful and easy learning for me.
Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)